# Translating intervals with 2 variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, locale, intervals

I want use my locale file to translate different intervals with quantities.

```
# Interval holds values from 0..2 (day, week, month)
@interval = 0

# Quantity holds values from 1..999
@quantity = 1
```

The implementation in the rails file should then look similar to this

```
<%= t("interval", count: @quantity, interval: @interval %>
```

The output should look like

```
1 Day
2 Days

1 Month
2 Months
...
```

Hope someone can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

In your locale file add something like:

```
en:
  interval:
    _0: 'Day'
    _1: 'Week'
    _2: 'Month'
```

and then use `pluralize` helper

`pluralize(@quantity, t("interval._#{@interval}"))`